# Lower Sum Inequality

Tags: calculus, integration

For every partiton P of [a,b], and functions f and g bounded on [a,b],
why does the sum of lower sums of f and g is less than or equal to the lower sum of f+g?

i.e), `L(P, f) + L(P, g) <= L(P, f+g)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any interval $[a,b]$, if we let $m_1=\mathrm{inf}_{[a,b]}f$, $m_2=\mathrm{inf}_{[a,b]}g$ then $\forall x \in [a,b]$:
$$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x) \geq m_1 + m_2. $$

Hence, since the infimum is at least as big as any lower bound, $\mathrm{inf}_{[a,b]}(f+g) \geq m_1 + m_2$.
Summing these up over all the subintervals of our partition gives the required result.

Comment: Which property of infimum ensures that inf_[a,b](f+g) >= m1 + m2?
May I ask you to state it directly?